# How to install java update 51 within terminal?

Tags: java, macos, command-line, terminal, installation

I am aware that it is possible on a mac running Mavericks to install programs using terminal (or any other form of the command line). However I need to specifically install the java 7 update 51 JDK (and JRE) on my mac. Although it is possible to install java through the normal installation methods using a GUI, I am just curious on if it possible, and how it is done through the command line.

Answer (score 0):

1) Download the image from Oracle web page

2) Mount the dmg image : sudo hdiutil attach .dmg

The image will be mounted to /Volumes/.

3) Run sudo installer /Volumes//.pkg -target /.

4) Unmount the image: sudo hdiutil detach /Volumes/.